# How to use New UI in Android Studio Flamingo

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea

I have seen new UI in `Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Beta 1` from official [documents](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/#new-ui-preview). Is it possible to use new UI in `Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to `Help | Find Action | Registry`, start typing the key name for `ide.experimental.ui`, then enable it. Restart the IDE.